# How do I group in Datagridview?

Tags: c#, datagridview, grouping

For example, when I type ROUTE 11 in the search section, I want it to show the data up to ROUTE 12. So my aim is to list the data **between ROUTE 11 AND ROUTE 12**. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: That's not grouping. That's filtering. The best way to do it depends on how you have loaded the data into the grid but the simplest option is to populate a `DataTable`, bind that to a `BindingSource`, bind that to the grid and then set the `Filter` property of the `BindingSource`. There's plenty of information and examples around.

Comment: To improve the quality of answers you should provide the code that you use to populate the grid and an example dataset. We cannot see `ROUTE 12` in the example or and can only speculate how or if the data is related by values that might be in other columns in the underlying dataset. If the only relation (between Routes 11 and 12) is the sequential position within the raw dataset then we will have to pre-process the data before we can apply grouping or filter logic.